# UIAlertView confirm delete button

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a `tableview`, and a delete function. Now I want an `UIAlertView` with a confirmation.

This is my code what I have now:

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {        
    AgendaModel* agenda = _meeting.agenda[indexPath.row] ;
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:agenda.id,@"id",agenda.name,@"name", nil];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure that you want to delete : %@?", agenda.name];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

It give's a popup, but because I didn't say to delete it isn't working. I want my app to do this code after the button Delete is pressed:

```
    NSString *delete_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RestAgendas/delete.json"];


    [_meeting.agenda removeObject:agenda];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [JSONAPI getWithPath:delete_url andParams:dict completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err) {
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];
```

Where can I define actions to buttons in a `UIAlertView`?

Sorry for the messy question, hope you guys understand my intentions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using AlertView (it's deprecated) and switch to UIAlertController.
It is more generic and replaces old alertView and actionSheet.
See the [documetation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController)
and [tutorial in swift](http://www.appcoda.com/uialertcontroller-swift-closures-enum/) or [tutorial in objC](http://hayageek.com/uialertcontroller-example-ios/).